# Why does i = 3 outside the for loop?

Tags: javascript

The condition in the loop specifies i<3. Shouldn't the loop stop at i = 2? if so, shouldn't outside loop be 2 not 3?

Thanks.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        console.log(i, " loop") 
        if(i%2===0){
          console.log (i,'even numbers in loop ');
        }
      }
      console.log(i, " outside loop")
```

Comment: The loop terminates once the condition fails.  It fails once i is not less than 3

Comment: The very last steps that the loop does are: increment `i` to 3, check if `i < 3`, it's not, so exit the loop.

Comment: This is the basic loop logic that you should definetely search and work about outside of the stackoverflow. It is Loop 101!

Answer (score 0):

**Loop:** it breaks as soon as `i < 3` is not verified, which means in the last iteration. More informations about [iterations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

**Scope:** because `i` is declared using `var`, which attaches the variable to the global scope. Using `var` is highly discouraged, use `let` instead, which declares variables in block scope. More informations about [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct behaviour of loops.
The loop starts with i = 0, then i = 1, then i = 2, then i = 3. oops i is no more less than 3, break the loop. that's what's going on, so when you log the value of i you get 3 and not 2.